# Wordpress. Is there way to acces post via custom url?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I migrating site now to wp. Now it has posts with url's like

```
example.com/module/title/some_digits/date/some_more_digits.
```

In wp it can be found at

```
example.com/?p=number
```

There are lot of external links directing to this posts, so if i will simply import all data in wp they will be useless.
I import posts from dump using wp_insert_post(), there is about 1k of them. May i somehow programmatically give a non-default url to post, to save old url style and prevent losing links?

Comment: make sure you have an htaccess file and set the "slug" to the old url and you should be able to get the old hierarchy. Alternatively, you may be able to write htaccess rule to redirect to your new location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess to redirect on new page or you can use this plugin for create custom url.

[Custom permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't solve all problem  because of I just gone crazy fixing it all manualy, but i look at plugin code and find some clues for my script.